# Realm query which also filters custom object data nested in another RealmObject class

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to create a query in Realm which filters out the custom object data which is itself is inside a RealmObject class. So for eg:

I have this class

```
public class Email extends RealmObject {

public static final String PROPERTY_SUBJECT = "subject";
public static final String PROPERTY_SENDER = "sender";
public static final String PROPERTY_BODY = "body";

  public String subject;
  public Sender sender;
  public Body body;
  public Date receivedDateTime;
}

public class Sender extends RealmObject {
  public EmailAddress emailAddress;
}

public class EmailAddress extends RealmObject {
  public String emailId;
  public String name;
}

public class Body extends RealmObject {
  public String content;
  public String contentType;
}
```

So I am trying to create a query which returns me all the results based on a user search to filter from "subject, emailAddress, name, bodyContent".

So I am trying it like this

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmQuery<Email> query = realm.where(Email.class);

query.beginGroup();
query.contains(Email.PROPERTY_SUBJECT, queryString);
query.contains(Email.PROPERTY_SENDER, ?);
query.contains(Email.PROPERTY_BODY, ?);
query.endGroup();

RealmResults<Email> results = query.findAllSorted(Email.PROPERTY_RECEIVED_DATE_TIME, Sort.DESCENDING);
```

I am trying to figure it out that how I can put Sender and Body object in the query as they are custom objects.

Can anyone help me out as I am a newbie to Realm?

Thank you in advance.. :)

Comment: I would consider just putting all these RealmObjects into one RealmObject (as a class). That way you avoid having to manage cascade deletes manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that what I was doing wrong in my Realm query. Basically, I was not using or() operator to combine multiple queries and that's the reason that I was not able to get the desired results.

Now I solved this problem on my own. Here is my solution:

```
    RealmQuery<Email> query = realm.where(Email.class);
    query.contains(Email.PROPERTY_SUBJECT, queryString, Case.INSENSITIVE).or()
        .contains(Email.PROPERTY_SENDER_NAME, queryString, Case.INSENSITIVE).or()
        .contains(Email.PROPERTY_SENDER_EMAIL, queryString, Case.INSENSITIVE).or()
        .contains(Email.PROPERTY_BODY_CONTENT, queryString, Case.INSENSITIVE);
    RealmResults<Email> searchResults = query.findAllSorted(Email.PROPERTY_RECEIVED_DATE_TIME, Sort.DESCENDING);
```

Where my Constants are something like this:

```
  public static final String PROPERTY_SUBJECT = "subject";
  public static final String PROPERTY_SENDER_NAME = "sender.emailAddress.name";
  public static final String PROPERTY_SENDER_EMAIL = "sender.emailAddress.address";
  public static final String PROPERTY_BODY_CONTENT = "body.content";
```

Also, you can see in the query that I have added `Case.INSENSITIVE`parameter as I wanted my search to be case insensitive.

Thank you for giving me suggestions above and trying helping me out. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [doc about link queries](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries).

first the `beginGroup()` and `endGroup` doesn't seem to be needed for your query.

try below:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmQuery<Email> query = realm.where(Email.class);

query.contains(Email.PROPERTY_SUBJECT, queryString);
query.contains("sender.emailAddress.name", "john");
query.contains("body.content", "some thing");

RealmResults<Email> results = query.findAllSorted(Email.PROPERTY_RECEIVED_DATE_TIME, Sort.DESCENDING);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "link queries", although in your case [you're just supposed to merge the objects into one.](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u)

```
public class Email extends RealmObject {
  private String subject;
  private String senderName;
  private String bodyContent;
  private String bodyContentType;
  private Date receivedDateTime;

  // getters, setters
}
```